# Stream podcasts to Xbox 360

Tags: windows-7, streaming, podcasts, xbox360, zune-software

I just rebuilt my Windows 7 64-bit machine and now my podcasts aren't visible to my Xbox 360's.  I download podcasts with Zune.  I added the c:\users\blah\podcasts folder to the "Videos" section of the Windows 7 library, but the folder didn't show up on my xBox 360.  Any other folders I have in the library show up on my 360 just fine.  Any ideas?

I have also tried turning on Sharing via the Zune software and that doesn't seem to work at all.